# how to get matched data after the lookup

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to get values by matching location ids. But I am getting error.in this locationId is an array like locationId[id1,id2] and location is an id.

Mongodb:

```
[err, assetsList] = await to(Assets.aggregate([
        {
             $match: {
                        "company" : new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(company)
                        // "auditAssetAvailability" : false
                     }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "audits",
                localField: "location",
                foreignField: "locationId",
                as: "asset_locations"
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: '$asset_locations'
        },
        {
            $match: {
                       "location" : { $in: [new mongoose.Types.ObjectId("asset_locations")] }
                    }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                "asset_locations":1, 
                "asset_name":1, "asset_code":1
            }
        },
    ]))
```

error:

```
message: "Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters"
```

it was working if I pass values like below:

```
{
 $match: {
          "location" : { $in: [new mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5f0968286fbe3f1278fb299f"),new mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5f09b8086fbe3f1278fb29a8")] }
                    }
        },
```

Example:
Audit record:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fb3dcec0a3b9b4b44fb77c7"),
    "locationId" : [ 
        ObjectId("5f0968286fbe3f1278fb299f"), 
        ObjectId("5f09b8086fbe3f1278fb29a8")
    ],
    "assetTypeId" : [ 
        ObjectId("5f09683a6fbe3f1278fb29a0")
    ],
    "auditUserId" : [ 
        ObjectId("5f0c1a96bde0191914faa169")
    ],
    "status" : true,
    "startDate" : ISODate("2020-11-03T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "endDate" : ISODate("2020-11-30T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "company" : ObjectId("5f0964314a8580273c5ce687"),
    "auditName" : "Q1 Audit",
    "auditStatus" : ObjectId("5fb36cec93e1df254c4b97c3"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-11-17T14:23:40.325Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-11-17T14:25:36.524Z")
}
```

asset record:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fb3e0620a3b9b4b44fb77d5"),
    "discarded_date" : null,
    "discordedNote" : null,
    "company" : ObjectId("5f0964314a8580273c5ce687"),
    "location" : ObjectId("5f09b8916fbe3f1278fb29a9"),
    "statusCondition" : "stock_type"
}
```

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: remove the `new` in `new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(company)` you dont need it

Comment: Try with `new mongoose.Types.ObjectId("$asset_locations")`. Using `$` to refer the variable

Comment: @Ifaruki thank you for responding, I tried that but it was not working.

Comment: you could try this `"location" : { $in: [{ $toObjectId: "$asset_locations" }] }`

Comment: @J.F. thank you for responding, actually` $asset_locations` is an object in that i have locationId array. if I use like `$asset_locations.locationId`. it is also not working

Comment: And using `{ $in: $asset_locations }`? But if the array is compound by string maybe will not work. Can you post your schema or a document example to test?

Comment: Yes, I just edited that data. please check once

Comment: It is working if I pass values like `{
 $match: {
          "location" : { $in: [new mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5f0968286fbe3f1278fb299f"),new mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5f09b8086fbe3f1278fb29a8")] }
                    }
        },`

Comment: I've tried to recreate the query but in your first `$match` stage you are looking for `company` field and is not into `assets`.

Comment: Sorry assets collection also have the `company` field. I missed it